# regex - how to search for overlapping triplets?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So i have this file with 4000 lines and i only want to print the lines with triplets in it. ie.

ADSKLF**AZE**GJSBN**AZE**KGRE

or

AFJEN**ABABA**JGORENFNEZJAJEO  (overlapping triplet)

I tried `egrep '(...).*\1'` but of course this doesn't print the overlapping ones.
Apparently you can use the look-around to solve this problem but I couldn't come up with the answer.

**SOLVED** http://regex101.com/r/hG3bO1/5

Comment: what language is this?  Is it case sensitive or case insensitive?  Might non-letter characters count as part of the triplets?

Comment: Have a link to where you heard about using lookaround to find overlapping triplets?

Comment: Would `BBBB` be an overlapping triplet?

Comment: To match `ABABA` as an overlapping triplet: [`(.)(.)\1\2\1`](http://regex101.com/r/tR4mP2/1)

Comment: yes BBBB is an overlapping triplet. i also tried `egrep '(...).*\1|(.)(.)\2\3\2|(.)\4{3}'` however, this didn't give the right amount of lines and the teacher said you could do it without the | operator using the lookaround regex

Comment: my apologies egrep `'(...).*\1|(.)(.)\2\3\2|(.)\4{3}'` does actually give the right answer. But I would appreciate it if somebody could come up with the better answer. Of course this is possible with triplets but is bad if you have bigger numbers. There is a solution without the | operator and the lookaround regex. Maybe look behind? I have no idea honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
(?=((.)(.)(.)))(\2|\2\3|.+)\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hG3bO1/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never have thought of that. thanks to you I came up with this solution [link](http://regex101.com/r/hG3bO1/3)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex.

```
(?=(.)(?=.\1)(.{2})\2)|(?=((.)\4\4))|(.{3})(?=.*?\5)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tR4mP2/3)